# Symfony only logging for dev environment while running in prod mode

Tags: symfony, logging

I am using [a PaaS provider (cloudControl)](http://cloudcontrol.com) for my Symfony app. Works fine in general.

But funny thing: In the `app/logs` directory, there is only a `dev.log`. Can someone explain what is wrong here?

(I surely didn't call the `app_dev.php`, which is by the way not possible on reomte systems - if `app_dev.php` isn't configured elsewise.)

Comment: You find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `web/app.php`, it should be:

```
//...
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);    
//...
```

You probably have `new AppKernel('dev', false);`

Comment: Why should I have a `dev` in my app.php (which is the file for production mode)?

Comment: So to be precise here: It surely is `prod`, not `dev`.

Comment: Well in your app_dev.php you need `new AppKernel('dev',true)` Are you still getting logs from app.php into dev.log ?

Comment: I'm not asking about `app_dev.php`.

Comment: That was the answer to your first question as the reason why would you want to have dev in there. Are you still having this issue?